# Resizing image using php

Tags: php

I am trying to resize my image by making it 200 x 200 while keeping the aspect ratio. I am trying to follow http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php to try to accomplish this. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $directory = "uploads/";
    $images = glob($directory."*.jpeg");
    foreach($images as $filename) {

        // Set a maximum height and width
        $width = 200;
        $height = 200;

        // Get new dimensions
        list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

        $ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

        if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
           $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
        } else {
           $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
        }

        // Resample
        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

        // Output
        imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
    }
?>
```

I took out the content type because it was giving me an error. Instead of outputting the resized image, it was outputting bunch of symbols like this:

`JFIF�����t��jw��E��4."�DN�9>m���4����P};WI��x"�`.

Anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Where did you have `content type` before?

Comment: Are you trying to resize them and save them or resize them and serve them? Even if you add the content-type header, you are still trying to output a byte stream of multiple jpeg images in a single request. It isn't going to work like you think it should.

Comment: I erased it because it kept giving me this error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sites/aejhyun.com/public_html/Syrian Project/index.php:555) in /home/sites/aejhyun.com/public_html/Syrian Project/index.php on line 558`

Answer (score 0):

You need to sent header to a browser so your output could be properly understand by browser. Add following line to your script:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');` before the foreach loop

Comment: However, I get this error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/sites/aejhyun.com/public_html/Syrian Project/index.php:555) in /home/sites/aejhyun.com/public_html/Syrian Project/index.php on line 558`

Comment: Well that means there is an output somewhere there. That is the real problem. First you send all the headers, then you output.

Answer (score 0):

This code must be at the very beginning of your file:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
```

And the above code should be standalone, you shouldn't have any HTML tags anywhere and it shouldn't be "PHP-included" anywhere.